# Magento 2 permissions Centos

Tags: magento2, centos

Just installed magento 2 on centos OS having problems with setting permissions for new user. The only apache group I get is nobody. So I've added the user to that group but cant set any permissions. Any ideas?

Comment: You can have look here https://magestar.in/magento-2-file-permissions-in-centos/

Answer (score 0):

What kind of hosting are you using and what kind of access you have? Have you even tryed to read official documentation? http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

Comment: We have root access on VPS

Comment: Are you interested to fix you issue? If yes, please reply to all my questions, thank you

Comment: yes I normally do it the Set ownership and permissions for two users way. The hosting is on dedicated vps

Comment: Of using nginx, just chown magento root folder with www-data:www-data in casa of Apache webserver, chown apache:apache. Then be shure that folders are 755 and files 644. Then reload/restart webserver. If this works, then move the problem on the users you are trying to create and give write ownership